# Openfire setup page

Tags: openfire

I'm trying to install Openfire 4.0.2 . My problem is that after restarting Openfire and pressing Admin Console I always see Setup Page. What should I do to fix it?

This is my openfire.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    This file stores bootstrap properties needed by Openfire.
    Property names must be in the format: "prop.name.is.blah=value"
    That will be stored as:
        <prop>
            <name>
                <is>
                    <blah>value</blah>
                </is>
            </name>
        </prop>

    Most properties are stored in the Openfire database. A
    property viewer and editor is included in the admin console.
-->
<!-- root element, all properties must be under this element -->
<jive>
    <adminConsole>
        <!-- Disable either port by setting the value to -1 -->
        <port>7090</port>
        <securePort>7091</securePort>
    </adminConsole>

    <locale>en</locale>

    <!-- Network settings. By default, Openfire will bind to all network interfaces.
      Alternatively, you can specify a specific network interfaces that the server
      will listen on. For example, 127.0.0.1. This setting is generally only useful
       on multi-homed servers. -->
    <!--
    <network>
        <interface>127.0.0.1</interface>
    </network>
    -->

    <!-- SPDY  Protocol is npn.
        (note: npn does not work with Java 8)
        add -Xbootclasspath/p:/OPENFIRE_HOME/lib/npn-boot.jar to .vmoptions file    -->

    <!--
    <spdy>
        <protocol>npn</protocol>
    </spdy>
    -->

    <!-- XEP-0198 properties -->
    <stream>
        <management>
            <!-- Whether stream management is offered to clients by server. -->
            <active>true</active>
            <!-- Number of stanzas sent to client before a stream management
                 acknowledgement request is made. -->
            <requestFrequency>5</requestFrequency>
        </management>
    </stream>

</jive>
```

Thank you.

Comment: On setup wizard, have you successfully completed it atleast once? Because there is no database configuration visible in openfire.xml you shared.

Comment: @shoaib-ahmad-gondal That is the problem I've completed setup wizard(which is in the browser) many times, I guess at least 20 or more.

Comment: try adding <setup>true</setup> as a direct child of <jive> like after <locale>en</locale> then check if the issue persists.

Comment: @shoaib-ahmad-gondal Now it gives me "database setup or configuration error".

Answer (score 1):

In a file like this you miss the database part, so probably you never finished the setup really.

However there are 2 flags you must add:

in **openfire.xml** `<setup>true</setup>`

as child of `<jive>` tag

and in ofProperty table of database

```
INSERT INTO OFPROPERTY (NAME,PROPVALUE) VALUES ('setup','true');
```

Comment: But if it was normal Openfire then database and setup tag would be there after setting all up?

Comment: yes, after a successfull setup you'll obtain those 2 values plus the database part in configuration. Let me bet, did you have Oracle database?

Comment: How do I include INSERT INTO OFPROPERTY (NAME,PROPVALUE) VALUES ('setup','true'); in my Openfire.xml?Thank you.

Comment: this have to be a insert on your real database, not in Openfire.xml

Comment: I think no, I didn't and I don't have Oracle databse.

Comment: nevermind, if you can run this insert on your openfire-database

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, you have to uninstall Openfire and after delete Openfire folder which is situated in C:/ProgramFiles(x86)/ and reinstall Openfire.

Answer (score 0):

The setup procedure of Openfire will, if it runs successfully, modify the content of the `openfire.xml` file. The most typical reason for this to fail is a file permission problem. Make sure that the user that is executing Openfire is allowed to read & write all files under the Openfire home folder.